# How to access a control under the UserControl of UserControl

Tags: c#

I have a main page that built up from a few parent UserControls, and some of this parent UserControls are built up from multiple child UserControls.

Currently the issue that I'm facing is that, I need to access a RadioButtonList from the main page and that particular RadioButtonList is located in the child UserControl.

Main Page contains parent UserControl.

Parent UserControl contains child UserControl.

Child Usercontrol contains a RadioButtonList.

Please help.

Comment: You should specify what technology you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your custom user control to expose the inner control, as such:

```
public RadioButtonList RadioButtons { 
  get { return _radioButtons; }
}
```

Where the instance is named `_radioButtons` accordingly.

You can do this all the way up the hierarchy, though it would get messy with a deep composite structure.

Comment: +1, When you realise how deep your structure goes sometimes it really emphasises why good design before hand helps!